# Android - detect if device connected with another hardware?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I've received a requirement for detect whether my android device is connected with any other hardware like (Audio, car etc) and notify user if disconnected with that hardware.
I really don't know if these hardware connects with device either using Bluetooth or Local Wi-Fi? Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the devices are connected via Bluetooth, register for the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` intent. It will fire whenever a Bluetooth device disconnects. Upon receiving this intent, examine its extras to find out which device disconnected:

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

For devices connected via WiFi, it depends on how the connection is established. If the device is a WiFi access point, register for connectivity change intents.

Answer (score 0):

If Bluetooth state is not opened, just only onReceive() Local Wi-Fi connected hardware devices list change!
If Bluetooth state is opened,onReceive() Local Wi-Fi connected hardware devices list change and onReceive() already paired bluetooth devices list change.

Comment: I think, what you saying to detect when Wi-Fi or Bluetooth connected or disconnected. But if if there is no disconnection for Wi-Fi or Bluetooth but connected device get disconnected?